# Display flex a few block with text in the same line

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create a few block/box with image and two text - headline and subtext, but headline sometimes has one sentence, but another more, so if one has one and second one has two I would like to center vertically this first one.

For subtext I would like to vertically to the top.

Here is code which I am trying to use:

```
<div class="row row-home">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <a href="/oferta.html#schody" title="Kliknij, aby dowiedzieć się wiecej."><img src="/images/home-1.png" alt="Schody" class="center-block img-responsive" /></a>
        <div class="text">
            <h2><a href="/oferta.html#schody" title="Kliknij, aby dowiedzieć się wiecej.">Schody</a></h2>
            <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipi scing elit. Nulla volut pat sem id turpis tempus efficitur. Maecenas eu bibendum sem.</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <a href="/oferta.html#balustrady-i-ogrodzenia" title="Kliknij, aby dowiedzieć się wiecej."><img src="/images/home-2.png" alt="Balustrady" class="center-block img-responsive" /></a>
        <div class="text">
            <h2><a href="/oferta.html#balustrady-i-ogrodzenia" title="Kliknij, aby dowiedzieć się wiecej.">Balustrady i ogrodzenia</a></h2>
            <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipi scing elit. Nulla volut pat sem id turpis tempus efficitur. Maecenas eu bibendum sem.</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <a href="/oferta.html#meble" title="Kliknij, aby dowiedzieć się wiecej."><img src="/images/home-3.png" alt="Meble" class="center-block img-responsive" /></a>
        <div class="text">
            <h2><a href="/oferta.html#meble" title="Kliknij, aby dowiedzieć się wiecej.">Meble</a></h2>
            <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipi scing elit. Nulla volut pat sem id turpis tempus efficitur. Maecenas eu bibendum sem.</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is CSS:

```
    #home .text {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 20px 30px;
    margin: 0px auto 40px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 236px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#home .text h2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
        z-index: 2;
    }
#home .text h3 {
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: justify;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align-last: center;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

It almost work, but if h3 has less text in one of blocks this text align to the bottom and h2 goes down.

Here is live [website to test](http://malykowal.linuxpl.eu/)

I create picture to show how it should work

[image: description how it should work]

Comment: Please review and comment on my answer, and let me know if something is unclear or missing. If not, then it would be great if you could accept the answer.

Comment: Sorry for my late, everything is okey, thanks a lot for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `h2` elements aren't aware of each other, I suggest you give them a height, or else you will need a extensive markup change

Here I added `height: 28px;` to the `.row-home .text h2` rule

```css
.row-home .text {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 20px 30px;
    margin: 0px auto 40px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 236px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.row-home .text h2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
        z-index: 2;
    }
.row-home .text h3 {
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: justify;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align-last: center;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">

  <div class="row row-home">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <a href="/oferta.html#schody" title="Kliknij, aby dowiedzieć się wiecej."><img src="http://malykowal.linuxpl.eu/images/home-1.png" alt="Schody" class="center-block img-responsive" /></a>
      <div class="text">
        <h2><a href="/oferta.html#schody" title="Kliknij, aby dowiedzieć się wiecej.">Schody</a></h2>
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipi scing elit. Nulla volut pat sem id turpis tempus efficitur. Maecenas eu bibendum sem.</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <a href="/oferta.html#balustrady-i-ogrodzenia" title="Kliknij, aby dowiedzieć się wiecej."><img src="http://malykowal.linuxpl.eu/images/home-1.png" alt="Balustrady" class="center-block img-responsive" /></a>
      <div class="text">
        <h2><a href="/oferta.html#balustrady-i-ogrodzenia" title="Kliknij, aby dowiedzieć się wiecej.">Balustrady i ogrodzenia</a></h2>
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipi scing elit. Nulla volut pat sem id turpis tempus efficitur. Maecenas eu bibendum sem.</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <a href="/oferta.html#meble" title="Kliknij, aby dowiedzieć się wiecej."><img src="http://malykowal.linuxpl.eu/images/home-1.png" alt="Meble" class="center-block img-responsive" /></a>
      <div class="text">
        <h2><a href="/oferta.html#meble" title="Kliknij, aby dowiedzieć się wiecej.">Meble</a></h2>
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipi scing elit. Nulla volut pat sem id turpis tempus efficitur. Maecenas eu bibendum sem.</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Updated with a second version based on a comment

If you want this to be really dynamic, you'll need to break it down like this, where you make the `col-sm-4` flex items

---

*Updated again, with a media query, to utilize Flexbox's `order` property and re-position the elements on smaller screens*

```css
.row-home {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.row-home .col-sm-4 {
  min-width: 0;
  flex-basis: 33%;
  padding: 10px 20px 30px;
}

.row-home .col-sm-4.vcentered {
  align-self: center;
}

.row-home .col-sm-4 h2 {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.row-home .col-sm-4 h3 {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: justify;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align-last: center;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .row-home .col-sm-4 {
    flex-basis: 51%;
  }
  .row-home .col-sm-4 * {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .row-home .col-sm-4:nth-child(3n+1) {
    order: 1;
  }
  .row-home .col-sm-4:nth-child(3n+2) {
    order: 2;
  }
  .row-home .col-sm-4:nth-child(3n+3) {
    order: 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-home">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <a href="/oferta.html#schody" title="Kliknij, aby dowiedzieć się wiecej."><img src="http://malykowal.linuxpl.eu/images/home-1.png" alt="Schody" class="center-block img-responsive" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <a href="/oferta.html#balustrady-i-ogrodzenia" title="Kliknij, aby dowiedzieć się wiecej."><img src="http://malykowal.linuxpl.eu/images/home-1.png" alt="Balustrady" class="center-block img-responsive" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <a href="/oferta.html#meble" title="Kliknij, aby dowiedzieć się wiecej."><img src="http://malykowal.linuxpl.eu/images/home-1.png" alt="Meble" class="center-block img-responsive" /></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4 vcentered">
      <h2><a href="/oferta.html#schody" title="Kliknij, aby dowiedzieć się wiecej.">Schody this is some extra text I added for test</a></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 vcentered">
      <h2><a href="/oferta.html#balustrady-i-ogrodzenia" title="Kliknij, aby dowiedzieć się wiecej.">Balustrady i ogrodzenia</a></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 vcentered">
      <h2><a href="/oferta.html#meble" title="Kliknij, aby dowiedzieć się wiecej.">Meble</a></h2>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipi scing elit.</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipi scing elit. Nulla volut pat sem id turpis tempus efficitur. Maecenas eu bibendum sem.</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipi scing elit. Nulla volut pat sem id turpis tempus efficitur. Maecenas eu bibendum sem.</h3>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought about this way, but what if h2 has 3 sencence/line? Height in this way should have more than 28px, I am looking for that way which automatically set property high

Comment: @user1195901 Will have a second look in a while...if a markup change is necessary, will that be okay?

Comment: Depends which :) I have to use h2 and h3, because it's important for SEO.

I found second problem, maybe you know how to help me:
I move CENTER-BLOCK from <img> to <a>, because I want to click only photo without margins, but after that horizontal doesn't work on IE and on other browsers but small than 768px.

Comment: @SkuterPL Here is an update with a second version, and sorry for delay, have been really busy (and got your mail by the way).

Comment: @SkuterPL Regarding your other issue with Safari, I can't help as I don't have and use Safari myself

Comment: I have just tested your code, really nice trick to create separate columns for each element, but on small screen (XS for BS) I want to see only 1 BOX (image + h2 + h3), but with this code I can't do this.

Comment: @SkuterPL Of course you can...I have updated my last sample with a media query, so try it out :)